# Improving Performance when Generating Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

as the title suggests, I have a performance problem when generating Jasper Reports in batches. A single report for say a single customer's bank statement takes 2 seconds to generate. To generate for 50 customers I have to generate each one and subsequently merge them all into a single file which i subsequently pass to a servlet, and this takes 2 x 50 seconds (Close to 2 Minutes). Assuming of course there's no traffic on my server or internet issues whatsover. Is there a way I can improve the performance of batch reporting like in my case? Are there special features of Jasper Reporting that I have not yet explored?

What I have done:
1. I've been able to save meaningless calls to the database to fetch much needed records, and narrowed it down to just one call. (And to display this on the User Interface takes roughly 4 seconds for the entire data to display).

2. I found a short article on Jasper's batch export using a `List` of `JasperPrint` Objects. But this did not improve the performance at all. I thought exporting the report once would help as opposed to exporting each single report once and subsequently merging the PDF bytes. But this was not the case.
3. I have explored grouping on the JRXML file so the entire data can be rendered once, but this also fails horribly as I need the detail band to be iterated over, not just for customers, but also for each customer's data.

Any help in improving the performance of batch exports for Jasper Reports would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the percentage of sql query vs jasper parsing during 2 second? Do you use the same query on user interface? How often data updated can you use catch? Or maybe generate reports with nightly/hourly jobs and made them available to download?

Comment: I don't use SQL queries on the templates. Data is fetched with JPA and worked on before being sent to the report. I have thought of downloading pre-generated reports when a printout is requested, but these reports and their data are computed on the fly (every single time the button is clicked). It is tiring, but that's what I've got for now.

Comment: check if you are compiling report templates 50 times for each customer ? Change it to compile only once. Make sure that actually generating 50 PDF report files is slow or is it merging them in single PDF file  thats slow (looks like you are sure its not data fetching) ? Show us some code ... we can only guess

Comment: thanks @jNick I understand the need to see some code. Would make things a lot easier if getting a sample wasn't going to be an issue. The report has already been compiled (from .jrxml to .jasper), and I simply fill in a customer's data and generate a pdf at the end of it. Then I do this 50 times for 50 different customers. Data fetching takes at most 4 seconds. But iteratively generating the reports then take longer. At this point, I would consider an alternative to jasper if it solves the problem of performance in batch exports.

Answer (score 1):

After some research and a lot of testing, I discovered Jasper wasn't really the problem. After achieving Report Grouping (gathering all the data and generating from one .jasper file at once), I discovered it didn't make much of a  difference from generating individual reports and merging together with a `PDFMerger` library. What made the difference was Code optimization. If one customer's report is generated in 2 seconds, I discovered it could be made better. These are the following steps I took to achieve this.

1. Fewer database calls if possible (Better JPA Queries)
2. Logic Optimization

These two alone made the difference.